# Text Processing - how to remove part of string from search results using sed?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, text-processing

I am parsing through `.xml` files looking for names that are inside HTML tags. 
I have found what I need, but I would just like to keep the family names.

This is what I have until now (`grep` command for the names + clean-up of the result, which includes removing the tags and the file name, I will later sort them and leave only unique names):

```
grep -oP '<name>([A-ZÖÄÜÕŽS][a-zöäüõžš]*)[\s-]([A-ZÖÄÜÕŽS][a-zöäüõžš]*)</name>' *.xml --colour | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' | sed 's/la[0-9]*//' | sed  's/$*.xml://'
```

The output looks like this:

```
Mart Kreos
Hans Väär
Karel Väär
Jaan Tibbin
Jüri Kull
```

I would like to keep the family names, but remove the first names.

I tried to use the following command, but it only worked for some names and not for the others:

```
sed -r 's/([A-ZÖÄÜÕŽŠ][a-zöäüõžš]+[ ])([A-ZÖÄÜÕŽS][a-zöäüõžš]+)/\2/g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should use [`cut`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)).** It is more adapted to what you're trying to achieve here. And you would avoid struggling with UTF-8 characters.

This would give you the expected result for all names in your sample output:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'm just so used to cleaning up with sed that I didn't think of the simpler solution. Is there a way to do it with sed tho? I figured it should work with grouping like I've put as an example, but it didn't.

Comment: @ajax23 Your `sed` command gives the same result as `cut` for me on Linux Manjaro. What output do you get?

Comment: It probably works for the names I've put as an example, but when going through all of the files some names are unaffected like _Miina Augsberg_ or some names get scrambled together like _Peter Ollisaar_ becomes _PetOllisaar_, so I must be missing something important. No such problem using **cut**.